# Getting print output onto the same line

Tags: python, printing

I am working on a network automation tool.  The logistics of it are working fine.
The script opens a text file which will have a list of devices to connect to.
As the script connects to the devices it prints out the various stages of the script.
The issue is the output for the devices is on a different line to the device itself.

In the text file I have these names:

```
device1
device2
device3
```

When the script runs the output comes out like this:

```
09:57:13: device1

Checking this device for available space 

09:57:15: device1

 Sufficient space available 

09:57:19: device2

 Checking this device for available space 
09:57:21: device2

 Sufficient space available 

09:57:25: device3 Checking this device for available space 

09:57:27: device3 Sufficient space available
```

basically I want all the outputs to look like they do for device3.  But at the same time I want the text file to be easy for someone to come along and paste a list of their devices into it.

The part of the script is pasted below:

```
with open('devices.txt', 'r') as routers:
    contents = routers.readlines()
    for host in contents:
#for device_type in device_types:
        global hostname
        u = 'autouser-netmri'
        p = 'tRB66J2S'
        host = host
        cisco = {
            'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
            'host': host,
            'username': 'autouser-netmri',#u,  # ssh username
            'password': 'tRB66J2S',#p,  # ssh password
        }

        now = datetime.now()
        logs_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print("" + logs_time + ": " + host + " Checking this device for available space ")
```

Comment: You have the line `host = host`. This does nothing. Perhaps you meant: `host = host.strip()`. I think you read newlines from the `devices` text file.

Comment: Spot on, thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of each line there is a newline character `\n` and print adds one too.

You should remove the newline from text read from file

```
host.strip()
```

Comment: I don't think you've actually tried either of your solutions yourself.

Comment: removed the second (wrong) solution